# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'durationms' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting this error when I run the case statement below. I think I have to convert at some point, but not sure where or how.

```
update [092018] 
set duration1 = duration 
where duration1 is null 
and (durationms > 100 and durationms < 1000)
```

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'durationms' to data type int

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask]. Please note that sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Could you paste the declaration of the table, please? I am pretty sure there is something wrong in the field datatype.

Comment: COLUMN_NAME ORDINAL_POSITION
durationms 11
DATA_TYPE
varchar
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
50
CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH
50

Comment: I do not know where it is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your `duarationms` column is text of some sort.  You may try casting it to integer:

```
UPDATE [092018]
SET duration1 = duration
WHERE duration1 IS NULL AND
    CAST(durationms AS int) > 100 AND CAST(durationms AS int) < 1000;
```

Note that for brevity you could have written the `WHERE` clause as:

```
WHERE duration1 IS NULL AND CAST(durationms AS int) BETWEEN 101 AND 999;
```

If you plan on doing arithmetic with the data contained in `durationms`, then consider making it a numeric/integer column.

**Edit:**

If the above query is still not working, then your data might be in even worse shape than we thought.  There could be non numeric data in the `durationms` column.  To flag out records which can't be cast to integer, use the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [092018]
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int, durationms) IS NULL;
```

Any records returned should have `durationms` values which can't be coerced into integers.

If your version of SQL Server does not support `TRY_CONVERT`, then here is another option:

```
SELECT *
FROM [092018]
WHERE durationms LIKE '%[^0-9]%';
```

Comment: @PhongDoan I edited my answer with a follow up you can try to find bad records.

Comment: My durationms is data type is varchar (20), I want to calculate with it then what to do?

Comment: Please review my answer and then if something is still not clear comment again.

Comment: I get this error: 'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name. it still does not work

Comment: Hi Phong, check my second update, and try the last query I gave.

Comment: It seems to work fine, but I do not see any record, can you explain what this sentence is for?

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you very much

Comment: Just out of curiosity, was there a problem with your duration data?